# How do I change the system Location settings to use my language of choice?

Tags: java, jdbc

**How do I  change the system Location settings to use my Location of choice?**

i have a following Exception in program:

ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified

How do I  change the system Location from source code?

Comment: Post the code that throws that.

Comment: Have you see https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=428906 ?